# Stopping a custom UIButton resetting titleLabel to IB default on event firing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

In IB I have a view with a UIButton of Type Custom, it has no image and the Title is set as "#placeholder"

The view is attached to a class that provides an `IBOutlet` and an `IBAction` for the button.

I set the button title with this: `ViewClass.ButtonOutlet.titleLabel.text = @"%@",stringifiedVariable;` whenever I need to.

This works ok. However, when I click the button, the titleLabel.text reverts back to "#placeholder".

I tried unchecking 'Highlighted Adjust Image' in the Drawing section (attributes tab) in the Inspector but the behaviour was still the same.

Can this change be prevented? or is there a better pattern that I should be using?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

UIButton has a special method for setting the label.

- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)title forState:(UIControlState)state

For instance

```
NSString *buttonText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",stringifiedVariable];
[ViewClass.ButtonOutlet setTitle:buttonText forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Check the documentation for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the text to not change when you click on it, the simplest way is take the title out of the button in IB and then use the setTitle: forState: method from Jongsma.

Comment: I originally tried this; the button did not display any text at all